# Wrong device-orientation returned

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, orientation

I think I found a bug in the UIDevice.orientation variable.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait{
        print("Orientation is Portrait")
    }
    else{
        print("Orientation is Landscape")
    }
}
```

Everything works fine if I hold the device(Iphone 5) in my hand, but if it lies flat on the table I get "Orientation is Landscape" even if everything is shown in Portrait and the device itself is not rotated.
Is there any possible way to do something against this?

// Edit: This test also fails within button-actions.

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is definitely not the best place to perform this test. Do you get the same result when performing this test in `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() ... }`?

Comment: I dont get it in viewDidLayoutSubviews, but I get in when i put in in a button-click-event.

Comment: Great, then problem solved.

Comment: no not completely! The problem remains when I click a button that has to do different things depending on the current orientation. I temporarily fixed it by adding an extra if with self.view.frame.width < self.view.frame.height, but I think this is a bad solution.

Comment: Your original question mentions nothing about a button.

Comment: I edited it. I just realized it. At first i thought your tip would solve the problem completely but it sadly doesnt.

Comment: First, it's *not* a bug - iOS has been around 10 years and only now (!) this comes to light. It's *much* more likely something on your end. (No offense meant.) Second, please show us code to reproduce this. And that means code that exhibits an understanding of `UIView` (and `UIViewController`) lifecycles. Expecting such a thing as orientation in `viewDidLoad` to work? Not when `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has yet happened. And what' this I hear about a `UIButton`? "Sadly", you don't mention this in your question. Peace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more orientations besides portrait and landscape. You are checking for portrait and assuming everything else is landscape. It is not. In this case, the actual orientation is likely “face up”.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third option UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat beside portrait and landscape and You are checking only for portrait